# Rails interpretes boolean 1 as false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, boolean

I have an annoying problem: I want to mark users as deleted, so I created a boolean db column named "deleted" and flagged a User as deleted. Now, when I search it:

```
ds = User.where(deleted: 1)
User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`deleted` = 1 LIMIT 11
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<
   User id: 4, 
   vname: "Max", 
   nname: "Muster", 
   ...
   emailverified: true,
   deleted: false>]>
```

Why does Rails interpret 1 as false? One is supposed to be true, as the following search shows:

```
ds = User.where(deleted: true)
User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`deleted` = 1 LIMIT 11
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<
   User id: 4, 
   vname: "Max", 
   nname: "Muster", 
   ...
   emailverified: true,
   deleted: false>]>
```

So I search for deleted = true and get a record where deleted = false ???

I need this for a test I am writing:

```
expect(user_after_deletion.deleted).to be true
```

But user.deleted is always false, even when 1 is stored in the db.

With the field "emailverified" everything works as expected. The columns are both tinyint(1).

I tried to rename the column, but still no luck.

Can anyone please point me to the right direction?
Thanks!

P.S.:
user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  attr_accessor :passwd_upd
  belongs_to :entitlement

  after_initialize :set_uid
  has_secure_password

  has_many :user_histories

 def self.automatic_deletion
    User.where("created_at > ?", (Time.now - 24.hours)).each do |u|
      u.deleted = true
      u.save(validate: false)
    end
  end

  def undelete
    self.deleted = false
  end
end
```

and the corresponding migration.

```
class AddDeletedToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_column :users, :deleted, :boolean
  end
end
```

Comment: Or you use custom `enum` to map to integers

Comment: Can you post the output of `User` from Rails console?

Comment: sure: 2.5.0 :001 > User
 => User (call 'User.connection' to establish a connection)

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the `User`'s model code and DB migration.

Comment: added some information and user model and migration - thank you all for your time and help

Comment: Still no luck: I deleted the column, recreated it with another name. I then build a new app from scratch, created a model, added a deleted column and everything works as expected. The difference between both apps: The real one came from rails 4 and was migrated to rails 5 and works with mariadb, the test-app was directly created with rails 5.1 and uses a sqlite db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "solved" it by updating Rails from 5.1.4 to 5.2.

Now I get:

```
ds = User.where(deleted: true)
User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`deleted` = 1 LIMIT 11
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<
   User id: 4, 
   vname: "Max", 
   nname: "Muster", 
   ...
   emailverified: true,
   deleted: true>]>
```

Sorry for stealing Your time.